# How to get google business reviews and display in my custom phtml file

Tags: review, magento2.4.1

I want to show the summary rating and customer review in my phtml file, how to get google business review by using API in a custom module or any best practice pls suggest.

Google Business Review API : https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Any reference welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$accountId = 'your_account_id';
$locationId = 'your_location_id';

$url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$accountId.'/locations/'.$locationId.'/reviews';    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
/*If data is in xml format
$output = simplexml_load_string($output); */
$allData = json_decode(json_encode($output), TRUE); // You will get all the data
?>
```

Comment: What is the best approach to use the above script in a custom module?  Is it helper beat option?

Comment: You have to use cron for getting data repeatedly and run this script in cron then you can store data in DB and get in phtml through block file.

Comment: Do you have any module for this, its very useful for me to understand.

Comment: You can refer this module. It's getting data from third party url and stored in DB.

https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-kiyoh

Comment: Is there any ready made module available?

Comment: Use cron job to auto run the scrip at regular intervals like in every 5 minutes - learn cron jobs from here - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/

Comment: @MitalShah How to configure google business Reviews https://snipboard.io/snAZKU.jpg

Comment: @MitalShah Can u pls join the chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123445/discussion-between-zus-and-vibhore-jain

Comment: @MitalShah Can u pls share the module, once i get the account id and location id i will add and use that module. Its really appreciated.

Comment: @MitalShah I have updated some important details on chat, can u pls see it, finally got the account id and location id, can u pls share the module pls.

Comment: @MitalShah I am shared account id and location id on the chat section, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123445/discussion-between-zus-and-vibhore-jain can you pls help me on that, thanks.

Comment: @MitalShah  I am sharing the details on chat section, can u pls help me

Comment: @MitalShah Anything else you want from my side? can u pls see the chat section i am shared details.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123445/discussion-between-zus-and-vibhore-jain

Comment: HI, can u pls help me to write the module, in chat i shared the details Thnaks

Comment: Can you pls check it, i just updated the values on chat section

Comment: Is it working now.

Comment: I shared a module in chat. please check and let me know is it working?

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339394/57334 thanks

Comment: @MitalShah Any help for auto-generate token  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339482/57334

Answer (score 1):

You should auto-run the PHP scrip every 5 minutes containing API curl code using the cron job. 
Learn Cron Job handling here -
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/

**Edit**
This custom module may be helpful
https://github.com/aitoc/magento-2-google-customer-reviews

Comment: May I know how to get Google reviews, is any custom module should I create?

Comment: This may be helpful - https://github.com/aitoc/magento-2-google-customer-reviews

Comment: I need to show google business revies on my custom page.

Comment: Hi i want to display google customer reviews on my custom phtml page.

Comment: Please share some code of your custom phtml page, what you already tried.

Comment: I am using amasty store locator extension, on that page i want show my google business review page,

https://store-locator-m2.magento-demo.amasty.com/amlocator/fashion-gallery/

Comment: I reached here, this is documentation and they are teaching how to use this, please check - https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_2:store_locator

Comment: Thanks for your link, I want to display the google reviews, not Magento reviews.

Comment: Have you tried @Mital_Shah code ? what output you got from that in your phtml page .. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123445/discussion-between-zus-and-vibhore-jain).

Comment: I have updated the details on chat, can u pls check it.

Comment: I am really new to API thing, can u pls help me with that, its really appreciated, thanks. I have updated detials on chat, can u pls help me.