# magento 2 - custom module - Error filtering template: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: magento2.4, magento-2-commerce

I am getting

Error filtering template: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Zero\Storelocator\view\frontend\templates\google_reviews.phtml on line 4

line no. 4: **$allData = array_slice($allcollection['reviews'], 0, 5, true);**

Full code: https://paste.ofcode.org/334bFgXch3bnAWJGaSr5wwh

Function, line no. 3 : **getCustomerReview()**

Function Code: FUll code : https://paste.ofcode.org/F7Jz4EUa5X9shkZF9MuRu6

function start from line no. 23

Why i am getting this error

**Error filtering template: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Zero\Storelocator\view\frontend\templates\google_reviews.phtml on line 4**

Comment: Did you try using php's method `isset()` to check if data exists in `$allcollection['review']`?

Comment: Where i can use and how to use it?

Comment: You mean line no.4 : https://paste.ofcode.org/334bFgXch3bnAWJGaSr5wwh

Comment: check it out https://paste.ofcode.org/fkqbXaRsb7Q2FKXcAzj6BZ

Comment: After add isset() my error :  Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: allData in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Zero\Storelocator\view\frontend\templates\google_reviews.phtml on line 14

Comment: line no. 14 : https://paste.ofcode.org/NNXrPVmZMHHrgr2C7L6bS4

Comment: put your all code inside `if isset()` scope that you want to check.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/vWv3jLU9FHCHUFVhMDGhPp like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126214/discussion-between-zus-and-abdul-samad-abbasi).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your curl call returns null sometimes. You can change this line
`return $allData;` in the `getCustomerReview` method with this

```
return $allData ?? ['reviews' => []];
```

Comment: After update : return $allData ?? ['reviews' => []];, i am getting   Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined index: reviews in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Zero\Storelocator\view\frontend\templates\google_reviews.phtml on line 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code with the isset condition before getting the data. You can use the below code for phtml file:

```
<?php
$allcollection = $this->getCustomerReview();
if($allcollection && isset($allcollection['reviews'])) {
    $allData = array_slice($allcollection['reviews'], 0, 5, true);
    foreach ($allData as $data) {  
        if (array_key_exists('comment', $data)) {
?> 
            <!-- Star Rating  -->
            <div><?php echo $data['starRating'] ?></div> 

            <!-- Comment  -->
            <div><?php echo $data['comment'] ?></div>

            <!-- Reviewer Name  -->
            <div><?php echo $data['reviewer']['displayName']; ?></div>

            <!-- review Age   -->
            <div><?php echo $data['createTime']; ?></div><br>
        
<?php   } 
    } 
}   
?>
```